# adding jsp page using ajax, as result of HTTP request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jsp

i have a JSP page called userPage.jsp which has 2 "tabs". clicking on each tab link shows the appropriate JSP page in a div

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#joinGamePanel" data-toggle="tab">Join a Game</a></li>
   <li><a href="#createGamePanel" data-toggle="tab">Create Game</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="joinGamePanel"></div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="createGamePanel"></div>
</div>
```

joinGamePanel div and createGamePanel div get their content via AJAX.
in default the joinGamePanel gets filled.

adding the content to the divs is written in an external .js file in a function `showPage`:

```
window.showPage = function(panel, loadPage) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: loadPage,
        timeout: 2000,
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("error");
        },
        success: function(r) {
            $(panel).append(r);
        }
    });
};
```

(i put the window prefix in order to try to fix the problem
but it didn't work..)

but there's a time i want the createGamePanel div to get filled (when i get a particular request)
i tried adding a  tab and call the `showPage` function from userPage.jsp but i get an error that the function is not recognized

is there another way of getting this done?

thank you

Comment: How are you calling the showPage function?

Comment: currently i'm calling it when i click on the <li> tabs to dynamically put code in the div. and i call it on window.ready to show the joinGamePanel div. all this code is in the same js file as showPage function